# Using RxJava with Paho MQTT

Tags: android, mqtt, rx-java2, paho

In my Android app, I have a service which has an instance of a class(call it MQTTClient) which publishes or subscribes to an MQTT server. I want to use RxJava with Eclipse Paho Android to manage MQTT subscribe and publish operations.

I am using `Single` observable and `SingleObserver` for publishing, and `Flowable` observable and `Observer` for subscribing. But I am stuck at a point where I cannot figure out when and how to dispose of the `Disposable`.

Here is the `Single` Observable from the `publish` method in `MQTTClient`

```
Single<IMqttToken> pubTokenSingle = Single.create(new SingleOnSubscribe<IMqttToken>() {
  @Override
  public void subscribe(final SingleEmitter<IMqttToken> emitter) throws Exception {
    final IMqttToken token = client.publish(topic, mqttMessage);
      token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
            emitter.onSuccess(token);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
            boolean hasNetwork = isOnline(context);
          if (hasNetwork && Objects.equals(((MqttException) exception).getReasonCode(),
              MqttException.REASON_CODE_CLIENT_NOT_CONNECTED)) {
            //connect client and retry MQTT pub
            try {
              //connect() is a method in MQTTClient
              //connect() method also utilizes RxJava2 Single.
              //Same issue of disposing a `Disposable` exists in that method as well 
              connect();
              //call the publish method again
            } catch (MqttException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              emitter.onError(e);
            }
          } else if (!hasNetwork) {
            emitter.onError(exception);
          } else {
            emitter.onError(exception);
          }
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Here is the `SingleObserver`

```
final Disposable[] disposable = new Disposable[1];
SingleObserver<IMqttToken> pubTokenSingleObserver = new SingleObserver<IMqttToken>() {
  @Override
  public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
    disposable[0] = d;
  }

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(IMqttToken iMqttToken) {
    //disposable[0].dispose();
    //Planning to use the above as last resort
    //Also thought of moving this to doOnSuccess
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable e) {
    //Put topic name, and mqtt message in SQLite

    //disposable[0].dispose();
    //Planning to use the above as last resort
    //Also thought of moving this to doOnError
  }
};
```

Someone suggested that I have a cleanup method in the concerned class which gets called when `onStop` is invoked.

I am concerned what would happen in case I use `disposable.dispose()` and the network operation is still in progress.

**How do I ensure that if the operation is incomplete then at least the details persist in the SQLite DB?**
I am hoping that the solution would be easily extensible for subscribing as well. If not then tell me about the possible pitfalls.

*This is a learning project where I am learning RxJava2 that is why I didn't opt for RxMQTT.*

Comment: Putting the clean up method in the appropriate lifecycle callback of the enclosing Activity, Fragment, or Service is the way to go here

Comment: @DavidRawson What about in-progress tasks for which the program won't receive `onSuccess` or `onError` callbacks to decide what to do in either of the case?